# Trouble with publishing simple .html site through FileZilla

Tags: html, deployment, web-deployment

I'm trying to publish a really basic site, using some webspace my college provided free for me. I've got access to a www and a data folder. The www is for the website and the data is well, well for the regular data. I've made a simple .html file with JS & CSS, it all works fine on my machine, but when I try to publish it, I can't access the secondary IndexEng.html file, despite that it works locally.

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong? Below is how the online web folder is published:

[image]

So just to be clear, Index.html works, the js & css gets loaded correctly, but the IndexEng.html does not work. I've tried IndexEng.html both next to Index.html and in the html folder, neither works. The following code is used:

```
 <a href="html/IndexEng.html"><button class="...">
      ENG
 </button></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buttons don't work the way you're expecting them to inside anchors.

If you just want a simple link to the indexEng.html page, you just need to specify the anchor:

`<a href="indexEng.html">This is the link text</a>`

You can style the link to look like a button using CSS.

Comment: Mmhm I tried that and locally it still works, but it still doesn't on the live version

Comment: Right, sorry. Error message is **The requested URL /xxx/html/IndexEng.html was not found on this server.** Even though the html folder exists next to Index.html and IndexEng.html is filled in

Comment: Make sure the file names are the correct case in your code. indexEng rather than IndexEng

Comment: Ooh I feel stupid... Yeah that solved the problem. n² facepalms required.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:
<button class="..." id="myButton">

</button>

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function () {
        location.href = "html/indexEng.html";
    };
</script>
```

Change location.href = "indexEng.html"; if you want to direct your button to what you have in your image above.